# Как последовательно выбирать данные из массива?

Tags: php

Есть скрипт, который заполняет базу данных данными, взятыми из массива. Сейчас данные с массива, добавляются случайно, как можно изменить скрипт чтобы данные добавлялись последовательно (Один, Два, Три,..,.., Один, Два,.......)?

Php:

```
if(100==100){

$rowsToCreate = 30;

$name = array("Один", "Два", "Три", "Четыре", "Пять");
$text = array("Текст 1", "Текст 2", "Текст 3", "Текст 4", "Текст 5");

do {
    $name2 = $name[array_rand($name)];
    $text2 = $text[array_rand($text)];

    $data = "INSERT INTO `blog` (id, name, text) VALUES (NULL, '".$name2."', ' ".$text2."' ) "; 

    $Result = mysql_query($data);
    $rowsToCreate--;
} while ($rowsToCreate>=1);


    if ($Result) {
        echo "<h3>Информация добавлена!!</h3>";
    }else{
        echo "<h3>Увы, но информация не добавлена!!</h3>";
    }

}
```

Бд:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `blog` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `text` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Comment: делаете простой цикл `for ($i = 0; $i < $rowsToCreate ; $i++) {...}`, а в цикле получаете текущий индекс через `$currentIndex = $i % count($name);`

Comment: А зачем Вы делаете `INSERT INTO (id.. ) VALUES (NULL`? Разве `id` у вас не PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: @cyadvert А как лучше сделать ( `INSERT INTO (id.. ) VALUES (NULL` ) ?

Comment: Если `id` это PRIMARY KEY и AUTO INCREMENT, то он вообще не нужен. База его сама создаст: `INSERT INTO blog (name, text) VALUES ('".$name2."', ' ".$text2."' )`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот так подойдет?

```
$inArrayCnt = 0; // здесь будем хранить порядковый номер записи из массива
do {
    $name2 = $name[$inArrayCnt];
    $text2 = $text[$inArrayCnt];

    $data = "INSERT INTO `blog` (id, name, text) VALUES (NULL, '".$name2."', ' ".$text2."' ) "; 

    $Result = mysql_query($data);
    $rowsToCreate--;
    $inArrayCnt++; // увеличиваем порядковы номер
    if ($inArrayCnt==Count($name)) $inArrayCnt=0; // если новый номер последний - обнуляем счетчик
} while ($rowsToCreate>=1);
```

Comment: Супер, спасибо от меня +.